# Derived class inherited getter, can't find a way to return the correct value

Tags: c++, inheritance, getter

I'm trying to have the derived class (Hero) inherit the code for a getter function from the base class (Entity). However, I can't find out how to access Hero's private variables (the correct values) through this getter.

I'm planning on assigning similar getters (about 10 total) to the Hero class as well as another derived class (Enemy). While I can technically write out each getter for the two classes, I rather limit code duplication. Is there anyway I can write the code in Entity and have the two derived classes inherit it?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Entity{
public:
    Entity() {
       this->speed = 0;
    }
    short getSpeed() {
       return this->speed;
    }

private:
    string name;
    short speed;
};

class Hero : public Entity{
public:
    Hero(short speed) {
       this->speed = speed;
    }

private:
    short speed;
};

int main()
{
    Hero hero1(2);
    cout << hero1.getSpeed() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output gives me `0`, which is the default value of entity. Is there any way to access the `hero1` value of `2` and output it?

Comment: Why do `Hero` and `Entity` each have a `speed`?  Only `Entity` should have one.

Comment: Your indentation scheme, though admittedly consistent, is more confusing, evem misleading, than helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you want a method of the base return a value that is private to derived? Thats not something that you usually do.

Step back and think what you actually want to achieve. If every `Enitity` has a `speed` member and if every `Hero` is an `Entity` then `Hero` needs no private `speed` in addition.

Instead `Hero` should initialize its `Entity` part in the constructor:

```
class Entity{
public:
    Entity(short speed = 0) : speed(speed) {}   // <- fixed constructor
    short getSpeed() { return speed; }
    void setSpeed(short s) { speed = s; }
private:
    short speed;
};

class Hero : public Entity{
public:
    Hero(short speed) : Entity(speed) {}    
};
```

I changed `Entity`s constructor such that you can pass an initial value for `speed`. Then `Hero`s constructor can properly initialize its `Entity` subobject.

> Is there any way to access the hero1 value of 2 and output it?

If you really want `speed` to be a private member of `Hero` then you should implement the getter in `Hero` also, just as you did it for `Entity`. However, having a `speed` in both classes and a getter for both is kinda weird. Choose whether `speed` belongs to `Entity` or to `Hero`, very unlikely you need it in both.

**One question you should have answered before writing code is: Who is reponsible for what?**

In the above example `Entity` is responsible for managing its speed. We can turn this around by saying: `Entity` only needs a way to retrieve the speed. How this is actually done is buisness of the subclasses (think of wooden chair vs elven archer wearing boots of speed +5). In code that would be

```
struct Entity{
    virtual short getSpeed() { return 0; }
};
```

I cannot explain better than others did already, so I quote from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual):

> Virtual functions are member functions whose behavior can be
>   overridden in derived classes. As opposed to non-virtual functions,
>   the overridden behavior is preserved even if there is no compile-time
>   information about the actual type of the class. If a derived class is
>   handled using pointer or reference to the base class, a call to an
>   overridden virtual function would invoke the behavior defined in the
>   derived class. [...]

TL;DR: `virtual` enables dynamic dispatch with pointers and references. It encourages subclasses to override the method with their own implementation.

Now subclasses can either be fine with the default implementation (wooden chair) or provide their own:

```
struct ElvenArcher : Entity {
    bool hasBootsOfSpeed = true;
    short baseSpeed = 10;
    short getSpeed() override {
        return hasBootsOfSpeed ? (baseSpeed+5) : baseSpeed;
    }
};
```

Here `override` declares that the method overrides one in a base class.

PS: Note that I put the important part in **bold**. It is not clear from your question what would be the correct way to write your code and this answer was mainly born from a comment that was too long for a comment. I tried to outline two extremes. What you actually need is probably somewhere in between.

Comment: @user4581301 i didnt dare to mention it in sloppy way, but accepted the challenge and added a second part to the answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement getSpeed in the hero class since speed is a private variable

Here is your corrected code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Entity{
public:
    Entity() {
       this->speed = 0;
    }
    short getSpeed() {
       return this->speed;
    }

private:
    string name;
    short speed;
};

class Hero : public Entity{
public:
    Hero(short speed) {
       this->speed = speed;
    }

    short getSpeed() {
       return this->speed;
    }
private:
    short speed;
};

int main()
{
    Hero hero1(2);
    cout << hero1.getSpeed() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Probably it is better to use protected instead

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Entity{
public:
    Entity() {
       this->speed = 0;
    }
    short getSpeed() {
       return this->speed;
    }

protected:
    string name;
    short speed;
};

class Hero : public Entity{
public:
    Hero(short speed) {
       this->speed = speed;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Hero hero1(2);
    cout << hero1.getSpeed() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Having that private duplicate of a variable is questionable. Fixing that would make the additional and OP-unwanted special getter in the derived class unneeded. Basically you are proposing to do exactly what OP specically wants to avoid.

Comment: Read the second part.